# Change a column format while ignoring (or keeping) NaN

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I want to change a column from a DataFrame which contains values of this format `hh:mm:ss` to a column containing the number of minutes (while keeping the NaN values)

I can't change it directly from the excel file so I've tried to do it with pandas (I'm working on a ML model with a health database):

```
38      00:35:00
39      00:50:00
40      00:45:00
41      01:32:00
42      00:29:00
43           NaN
44      00:45:00
45      00:13:00
46      00:20:00
47      00:31:00
48      00:54:00
49      00:43:00
50      02:33:00
```

I tried to separate the values from the NaN values using a mask then convert to minutes with `str.split()`

````
df1 = df['delay'][df['delay'].notnull()].astype(str).str.split(':').apply(lambda x: int(x[0]) * 60 + int(x[1]))```
df2 = df['delai_ponc_recal_calc'][df['delai_ponc_recal_calc'].isnull()]
````

But then I cannot merge to two series without loosing the order (I get the NaN values with the correct indexes at the end of the merged series)

```
39        50
40        45
41        92
42        29
44        45
45        13
46        20
47        31
48        54
49        43
50       153
43       NaN
```

I also tried to go from `hh:mm:ss` to minutes with `datatime.time` and `timedelta` using a loop (without using a mask) but I  still can't have a column (series or DF) with the all the values in minutes while keeping the NaN ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) to convert the `delay` column to pandas timedelta series then divide it by `Timedelta` of `1 min` to get total minutes:

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['delay'], errors='coerce') / pd.Timedelta(1, 'min')
```

---

```
39     50.0
40     45.0
41     92.0
42     29.0
43      NaN
44     45.0
45     13.0
46     20.0
47     31.0
48     54.0
49     43.0
50    153.0
Name: delay, dtype: float64
```

Comment: With this technique I get this error message : TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

Comment: I don't think you should be getting that error..Are you sure? though you can try something like `pd.to_timedelta(df['delay'].astype(str), errors='coerce') / pd.Timedelta(1, 'min')`

Answer (score 1):

Here are some possible solutions:

**Input**:

```
       delay
38  00:35:00
39  00:50:00
40  00:45:00
41  01:32:00
42  00:29:00
43       NaN
44  00:45:00
45  00:13:00
46  00:20:00
47  00:31:00
48  00:54:00
49  00:43:00
50  02:33:00
```

**Method 1: `pd.to_datetime`+ `map`**

```
df['delay'] = pd.to_datetime(df['delay'])

#using lambda function 
df['delay2'] = df['delay'].map(lambda x : x.hour*60 + x.minute)

print(df['delay2'])
#df.drop(['delay'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

**Method 2: `pd.to_datetime`+ `dt`**

```py
#converts time columns to pandas datetime64ns format
df['delay'] = pd.to_datetime(df['delay']) 

#using dt to extract hour and minute data
df['delay2'] = df['delay'].dt.hour*60 + df['delay'].dt.minute 
print(df['delay2'])
```

**Output**:

```
39     50.0
40     45.0
41     92.0
42     29.0
43      NaN
44     45.0
45     13.0
46     20.0
47     31.0
48     54.0
49     43.0
50    153.0
Name: Time, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Sorry for being late
With this I get this : 
`39     NaN
40     NaN
41     NaN
42     NaN
43     NaN
44     NaN
45     NaN
46     NaN
47     NaN
48     NaN
49     NaN
50     NaN
Name: delay, dtype: float64 `

Comment: This is weird. I tested again works for me. I just did some small changes in the code to make it fit your columns names. Can you try again?

Comment: Can you try now? I have added an another method as well. Should work now.

Comment: I get this for both :    TypeError: <class 'datetime.time'> is not convertible to datetime

Is it because the df['delay'].dtypes is object ??

Comment: Hey sorry my mistake, it's working with pd.to_datetime(df['delay'].astype(str)) !
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `errors='ignore'` for general cases as follows:

```py
df['column_name'].astype(int, errors='ignore')
```